# Can I use my master's degree thesis as a Research Project Proposal for a phd application?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, thesis

Can I use my master's degree thesis (a pilot study not published) as a Research Project Proposal for a PhD application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can repeat your MS work to get a doctorate, then the answer is no. If you are asking whether you can work to resolve still-open research questions that you already worked on earlier then the answer is a qualified yes.

But it depends on where you are and also on your advisor. In the US, for example, you don't normally need to make such a proposal to *apply* for doctoral study. Other places you do, and in those places the advisor will need to ok the proposal.

It's *acceptance* also depends on whether the advisor would consider the proposal to have sufficient *depth* to be suitable as a doctoral research project. So, again, if you are looking for an easy way through the doctorate, the answer would be a likely no.

But in the right place, with the right advisor, and the right problem, it can all come together for a yes, and your prior work might be considered a plus.